# Multiple oauth client spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have two tables, in each each one differents users , there are two applications web that are connected to my Spring BackEnd, each frontEnd application has one table of users . I want that the user of each table connect with differents clientId and clientSecret. I tried to create two authorization servers but it's appears that wouldn't work.

```
public class ClientAuthorizationServerConfiguration extends 
AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired 
private ClientConfigurationProperties clientConfiguration;

private TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
private RepositoryClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
        throws Exception {
    endpoints
            .tokenStore(this.tokenStore)
            .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
            .userDetailsService(clientDetailsService);

}
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws 
Exception {
    clients 
            .inMemory()
            .withClient(clientConfiguration.getClientId())
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
            .authorities("USER")
            .scopes("read", "write")
            .resourceIds(ClientApiResourceServerConfiguration.RESOURCE_ID)
            .secret("{noop}"+clientConfiguration.getClientSecret());

}



@Bean
@Primary
public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
    DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
    tokenServices.setTokenStore(this.tokenStore);
    return tokenServices;
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
  return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}

}
```

> this is my second authorization server

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Order(1)
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends 
AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private ApplicationConfigurationProperties configuration;


@Autowired
private RepositoryClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;




private TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

@Autowired
@Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
private RepositoryUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
        throws Exception {
    endpoints
            .tokenStore(this.tokenStore)
            .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);

}

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws 
Exception {
    clients 
            .inMemory()
            .withClient(configuration.getClientId())
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
            .authorities("USER")
            .scopes("read", "write")
            .resourceIds(RestApiResourceServerConfiguration.RESOURCE_ID)
            .secret("{noop}"+configuration.getClientSecret());

}


@Bean
@Primary
public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
    DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
    tokenServices.setTokenStore(this.tokenStore);
    return tokenServices;
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
  return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add one centralized database, only for authentication purpose. This database will have all clients information (Client ID, Client Secret etc.) and all users information (mostly username and passwords only). Complete user information will remain in their respective databases, but this authentication database will have only user credentials.

All your applications can authenticate themselves using Client Credentials grant type. Spring provides [OAuth2RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestTemplate.html) to make authenticated REST requests.

All your users (from both applications) can as well authenticate themselves using one centralized authentication server and authentication database.

Comment: I think if i try that , all the users could entrer to both application, I made 2 table in my Database, the first for app1 and the second for app2 , but if they both have same oauth client id and secret they could easly entrer to both of them .

Comment: In OAuth context, app1 is one client and app2 is another client. Both these applications will have different client credentials. 
In User table, user should have foreign key pointing to a client. This will help in identifying users belongs to which client.
Now, for example, user of app1 tries to login, user will enter his credentials, then behind the scene (app1 will need to authenticate itself if client credentials grant type is enabled) app1 will takes those user's credentials, add its client credentials and if user belongs to that client, it will get token from authentication server.